# Does there exist an uncountable dimensional real vector space $X$ such that $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ is a Banach space for any norm $\|\cdot\|$ on it?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Does there exist an uncountable dimensional real vector space $X$ such that $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ is a complete  space  for any norm $\|\cdot\|$ on it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. On every infinite-dimensional real (or complex) vector space, there are comparable but not equivalent norms, i.e. there are norms $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_1$ and $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_2$ with

$$\lVert x\rVert_1 \leqslant \lVert x\rVert_2$$

for all $x\in X$, but there is no $C \in (0,+\infty)$ with

$$\lVert x\rVert_2 \leqslant C\cdot \lVert x\rVert_1$$

for all $x\in X$. By the open mapping theorem, at most one of $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_1$ and $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_2$ can make $X$ into a Banach space.

To see the existence of such norms, consider a Hamel basis $\{ e_{\alpha} : \alpha \in A\}$ of $X$ and take two functions $f_1,\,f_2 \colon A \to (0,+\infty)$ with $f_1(\alpha) \leqslant f_2(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha\in A$ and $\frac{f_2(\alpha)}{f_1(\alpha)}$ unbounded. Then define

$$\Biggl\lVert \sum_{\alpha \in A} c_{\alpha}\cdot e_{\alpha}\Biggr\rVert_i = \max \{ f_i(\alpha)\cdot \lvert c_\alpha\rvert : \alpha \in A\}.$$

Comment: I knew that  for any infinite dimensional vector space , there exist comparable but not equivalent norms ; the connection with completeness was indeed the open mapping theorem . Awesome answer ! Thanks very much .

Comment: @Daniel Fischer, does this show that an infinite dimensional space is complete wrt at most one norm?

Comment: @SahibaArora No, there can be many inequivalent norms that make an infinite-dimensional space a Banach space. For example all spaces $\ell^p(\mathbb{N}), \, 1 \leqslant p \leqslant +\infty$ have the same algebraic dimension, $2^{\aleph_0}$, and thus they are all algebraically isomorphic. For each $p$, let $f_p \colon \ell^1(\mathbb{N}) \to \ell^p(\mathbb{N})$ be an isomorphism (as vector spaces, not as normed spaces), and let $\lVert x\rVert_{p} := \lVert f_p(x)\rVert_{\ell^p(\mathbb{N})}$. Then each of these norms makes $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ a Banach space, but no two are equivalent.

Comment: @DanielFischer, could you quote a source where I can read more detail about construction on inequivalent norms on infinite dimensional space?

Comment: @SahibaArora Sorry, I can't. There's a remark or two in many books, but I don't remember any book dealing with it extensively. I just remember a couple of constructions and (try to) assemble them when needed.

Comment: @DanielFischer, doesn't any book prove that if on a vector space any two norms are equivalent, then the space is finite dimensional? Or say something about this?

Comment: @SahibaArora I don't know. "Finite dimension implies all norms are equivalent" is of course standard, proved in most introductional books on functional analysis. Which books (if any, but there probably are such) prove "all norms equivalent implies finite dimension", I can't say. I don't remember reading it in any book I've read.